# Can a Custom DataProvider class expose Custom Templates?

Tags: sitecore

I am currently in the process of writing a custom DataProvider. Using the [Intergrate External Data](http://sdn.sitecore.net/developer/integrating%20external%20data%20sources/examples.aspx) documentation.

I've managed to show the external data in the Sitecore back end. However whenever I try to view the data in the items I created, I am getting an error

```
Null ids are not allowed. <br> Parameter name: displayName
```

There seems to be precious little on the subject on how to create a custom `DataProvider` on the Sitecore Developer Network.

The example on their website seems to only show how to import a SINGLE item into a static database. However I am simply trying to merge some items into the hierarchy and I can't find any useful documentation.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that one of your methods that should return an ID doesn't. It might be GetChildIds and/or GetParentId.

Nick Wesselman wrote a good article about it gathering all the information including an example on the Marketplace. I think that is your best start. [You can read it here.](http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2011/January/Black-Art-of-Sitecore-Data-Providers)

Comment: Thanks Jens. Already looked at that. Finally managed to get it working now. Turns out that I need to add the Templates/Template Sections/Template Fields into my GetParent/GetChildren methods.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to include at the very least, the Fields->Section->Template in the `GetParent` method. To be on the safe side I included the Fields/Sections/Templates into my implementations of

- `GetChildIDs`
- `GetItemDefinition`
- `GetParentID`

It wasn't obvious that this was the case, since I had in fact implemented the `GetTemplates` method correctly, and I had expected that should be enough.